# Is there an easy way to replace usages of constants?

Tags: java, string, android-studio, constants

I have declared a bunch of constants and I'm wondering if there is a way to basically replace each usage of the constant with its value.

For example I have code similar to:

```
private static final String STRING = "text";
```

where the constant `STRING` is used many times throughout my code.

Is there any easy way to replace all the `STRING` usages with its value `text` without having to manually go through each one?

Comment: Click it, then CTRL + ALT + N

Comment: Refactor, or Find and Replace.

Comment: The CTRL + ALT + N and then "Inline all and keep the field" was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I just wonder why you want to do that....

Comment: This might be asking a lot but is there any way to do that on multiple constants at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Basically every modern code editor has a "Find and Replace" option built into it, I don't use Android Studio but it's properly under the "Edit" menu(Properly "Ctrl + F" or "Ctrl + H").

Comment: The trouble with this is that it tends not to be sensitive to context. For example, if you have two constants with the same simple name, you might accidentally replace "the wrong one". Far better to use refactoring tools than text editing tools.

Answer (score 0):

For replacing usage of Contstant, use shortcut keys **Shift+F6** or just **Right** click on variable and then click on **Refactor** option